# Finding words that are the reverse of each other in a file

Tags: python, file, loops, iterator, for-loop

Sorry for this newbie question, just got starting. I want a simple program to look in a file for reverse words, so a wrote this source, but it doesn't work. After it goes into the second "for" loop, it doesn't go back to the first loop, instead it ends the program. Any clue?

```
def is_reverse(word1, word2):   
   if len(word1) == len(word2):
     if word1 == word2[::-1]:
       return True   
return False

fin = open('List.txt') 
for word1 in fin:
    word1 = word1.strip()
    word1 = word1.lower()
    for word2 in fin:
      word2 = word2.strip()
      word2 = word2.lower()
      print word1 + word2
      if is_reverse(word1, word2) is True:
             print word1 + ' is the opposite of ' + word2
```

EDIT: 
  I tried to loop a file vs a list, and got a curious (to me) result. If I use this code everything works:

```
def is_reverse(word1, word2):
  if len(word1) == len(word2):
      if word1 == word2[::-1]:
        return True
  return False

fin = open('List.txt')
fin2 = ['test1','test2','test3','test4','test5']
for word1 in fin:
    word1 = word1.strip()
    word1 = word1.lower()
    for word2 in fin2:
      word2 = word2.strip()
      word2 = word2.lower()
      print word1 + word2
      if is_reverse(word1, word2) is True:
             print word1 + ' is the opposite of ' + word2
```

If I exchange fin and fin2 the first loop does only one itineration. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Paste the real code, this one has syntax errors and undefined variables.

Comment: What do you think of my solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for word1 in fin` iterates line-by-line, so `word1` is really a line, not a word.  Is that what you intended?

`for word2 in fin` is using the same iterator, so I think it will consume all the input, and `for word1 in fin` will only be done once.

So the simplest change is to have two files, `file1` and `file2`, and re-open file2 for every pass thru the loop.

```
def is_reverse(word1, word2):   
   if len(word1) == len(word2):
     if word1 == word2[::-1]:
       return True   
return False

file1 = open('List.txt') 
for word1 in file1:
    word1 = word1.strip()
    word1 = word1.lower()
    file2 = open('List.txt')
    for word2 in file2:
      word2 = word2.strip()
      word2 = word2.lower()
      print word1 + word2
      if is_reverse(word1, word2):
             print word1 + ' is the opposite of ' + word2
```

But probably a better way is to read the files once into a list and then iterate over the list rather than the file, e.g.

```
def is_reverse(word1, word2):
    if len(word1) == len(word2):
        if word1 == word2[::-1]:
            return True
    return False

file = open('List.txt')
words = list(file)
for word1 in words:
    word1 = word1.strip()
    word1 = word1.lower()
    for word2 in words:
        word2 = word2.strip()
        word2 = word2.lower()
        print word1 + word2
        if is_reverse(word1, word2):
            print word1 + ' is the opposite of ' + word2
```

---

To answer your other question, about why you can iterate over the same list twice but not over the same file:

A `for element in iterable` loop asks the `iterable` for its *iterator* by calling `iterable.__iter__`.

When Python asks a file for its iterator, the file returns itself.  This means that every iterator over a file shares the same state/position.

```
>>> file = open('testfile.txt')
>>> it1 = iter(file)
>>> it2 = iter(file)
>>> id(it1)
3078689064L
>>> id(it2)
3078689064L
>>> id(file)
3078689064L
```

When you ask a list for its iterator, you get a different iterator every time, with its own separate information about its position.

```
>>> list = [1,2,3]
>>> it3 = iter(list)
>>> it4 = iter(list)
>>> id(it3)
3078746156L
>>> id(it4)
3078746188L
>>> id(list)
3078731244L
```

---

Postscript

As Hugh points out, iterating over the list of words for each word is going to be very inefficient.

Here's a way that's much faster.  Change `List.txt` to a very big file, e.g. `/usr/share/dict/words` on a Linux system to see what I mean.

```
words = []
wordset = set(())

file = open('List.txt')
for line in file:
    word = line.strip('\n')
    words.append(word)
    wordset.add(word)

for word in words:
    reversed = word[::-1]
    if reversed in wordset:
        print word + ' is the opposite of ' + reversed
```

Comment: Correct. The easiest solution is to change the open line to `fin = list(open('List.txt'))` to cache the entire file in memory. (And probably the source file is known to only contain one word per line - common in homework assignments...)

Comment: Ok, I think is the best answer to my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to compare the list against itself, you can avoid an iteration by testing for value in set:

```
def getWords(fname):
    with open(fname) as inf:
        words = list(w.strip().lower() for w in inf)
    ws = set(words)
    words = list(ws)
    words.sort()
    return words, ws

def wordsInReverse(words, wordset):
    for w in words:
        rw = w[::-1]  # reverse the string
        if rw in wordset:
            yield w,rw

def main():
    words, wordSet = getWords('List.txt')

    for w,rw in wordsInReverse(words, wordSet):
        if rw >= w:  # don't print duplicates
            print('{0} is the opposite of {1}'.format(w, rw))        

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

and to cross-compare two files:

```
from itertools import chain

def main():
    words1, wordSet1 = getWords('List1.txt')
    words2, wordSet2 = getWords('List2.txt')

    for w,rw in chain(wordsInReverse(words1, wordSet2), wordsInReverse(words2, wordSet1)):
        print('{0} is the opposite of {1}'.format(w, rw))
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're iterating over "fin" in both loops (although your example code has a mysterious variable "x" in the first loop).  Instead try using a separate handle to the file in each loop, like this:

```
fin1 = open("list.txt")
for word1 in fin1:
    fin2 = open("list.txt")
    for word2 in fin2:
        ...etc...
```

Comment: But is this a good idea though? I mean, if `n` was the number of lines in the file, how many times would the file be opened/read? `n+1` times, right? There should be no need to read the file more than once.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers! The X variable was the result of some testing i did with lists, so I edited the code. I noticed that even if I use a file and a list, the loop still halts if I load it into a variable before starting the loops, but only if the file is used for loop2.

Comment: @nuNce: The reason why files and lists are different is that `file.__iter__` returns self, but `list.__iter__` returns a new object on each call.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

> There should be no need to read the file
>   more than once.

– Klaus Byskov Hoffmann

It means that it's overconsuming time to iterate two times on the words: if a file contains 1000 words, the reversal of each word will be potentially compared  to 1000 words, that is 1000000 comparisons in total;

Here's a code with only one iteration, a dictionary reminds what it has already seen

```
with open('palindromic.txt') as f:
    ch = f.read()
    li = [ w for w in ch.split() if len(w)>1 ]

dic ={}
pals = set([])

for line in li:
    word = line.strip().lower()
    if len(word)>1:
        if word not in dic:
            dic[word] = 1
            if word[::-1] in dic and word[::-1]!=word:
                pals.add(word)
        else:
            dic[word] += 1


for w in pals:
    print w,dic[w],'  ',w[::-1],dic[w[::-1]]
```

[ w for w in ch.split() if len(w)>1 ] must be improved to remove parentheses, apostrophes, etc  from each word